# How to remove value after some special character

Tags: javascript

I am getting my string like this.

ex : 1

`input.value = " United State; UK"`

Ex 2:

`input.value = " United State; UK; AUS"`

Or so on.

Well I want to remove last value
UK in example one and AUS in example 2
What I am trying here is

```
var splitValue = input.value.split(";");
    splitValue.splice(splitValue.length-1);
    input.value = splitValue.join(";");
```

But don't know why I am not getting the correct answer. My last value is loosing its semicolumn.

How to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var input = " United State; UK; AUS"

var newinput = input.split(';');
newinput[newinput.length-1] = "";

console.log(newinput.join(';'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this

```
input.value.replace(/;[A-Za-z0-9\s]*$/,"")
```

This will give you what you need. Also try to understand this, this will remove Alphanumeric value with spaces after `;`

You can replace `[A-Za-z0-9\s]` with what you know are allowed characters after the `;`

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this. But it will help me if you elobrate or any link so I can read about regular expressions

Comment: This is the best link I know to learn Regexp: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

One approach here is to use a regex which will consume and capture everything up to, and including, the final semicolon.  Everything after that is the final word which you wish to discard.

```js
var str = 'United States; UK; AUS';
console.log(str.replace(/(.*;).*$/, '$1'));
```

**Output:**

```
United States; UK;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, This is also a smarter way to do

Answer (score 0):

Give a try

```
str = " United State; UK";
var arr = str.split(";");
arr.pop();
console.log(arr.join(";"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this..

```
var Inputvalue = "United State; UK; AUS";
Inputvalue  = Inputvalue .substr(0, Inputvalue .lastIndexOf(";"));
alert(Inputvalue );
```

Comment: But in this case `;` is missing from the last value. UK here

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
var a = " United State; UK";
var b = " United State; UK; AUS";
var value = "";
var value1="";

//example 1
var splitValue = a.split(" ");
for (var i = 1; i < splitValue.length - 1; i++) {
  value += splitValue[i]+" ";
}
console.log(value);
//example 2
var splitValue = b.split(" ");
for (var i = 1; i < splitValue.length - 1; i++) {
  value1 += splitValue[i]+" ";
}
console.log(value1);
```